# octobercms open modal popup using partial and static pages plugin

Tags: octobercms

I am using **OctoberCMS** and i found this a very good CMS indeed.

I am having trouble opening **popup modal**.

I have used a [static pages](https://octobercms.com/index.php/plugin/rainlab-pages) plugin and created a page over there. Call as **static_page**.

Then i have simply created a partial and put this code there. Call as **partial_popup**.

```
<a
    data-control="popup"
    data-ajax="demo"
    href="javascript:;"
    class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
    Launch Ajax Form
</a>
```

Then i have called this partial in my static page and i am able to see the button kind of anchor tag over there.

Then i have created one CMS page call it **demo** (Note: Not static page but CMS page instead) which i mentioned in my popup modal `data-ajax="demo"` to open and then after, i have executed my **static_page** in browser and clicking on that anchor/button.

But i am unable to open any popup modal and i am also not able to see any error in my firebug console.

Can someone guide me how can i achieve this, in future i would also like to add some extra parameters in query string like sending **id** and getting records based on that **id** making database queries and hence i have created partial and cms page. But for now i would like to achieve this atleast as a first step.

Any help, suggestions will be highly appreaciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys,

Eventually, I have used https://github.com/saribe/eModal library and it seems like it is working based on my above scenario as this library is providing an ability to open the modal with ajax request.

Thank you.

Comment: thanx this is nice suggestion